# (React.js)Broken images after using Webpack to import multiple from a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React and currently trying to build a card game. I used the webpack importAll(r) to retreive images for poker cards. But the image appears broken, by inspecting the property:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVZD7.png)

This is the code of Card.js:

```
const images = importAll(require.context('./Asset', false, /\.png$/)); 
    console.log(images);

const Card = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={images['NAP-01_Back.png']} alt = "image" /> 
        </div>
    )
}

function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;

}
```

In App.js I simply put `<Card/>` inside the div.

The folder structure is as below:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE9eP.png)

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You are missing 's'..here './Asset'..

Comment: Apologies, it should be Asset in the folder structure.

Comment: Every thing looks ok to me, check if the image name is correct..

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the code and it worked out this time  magically.